# Scaling a cube down

Tags: modeling

I'm wanting to scale a cube down so that it is half the height. From the top down without moving any other parts of the object. I've searched for a while now and just can't find an answer.

Comment: Could you please accept m.ardito as it's a more correct and better answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to scale a simple shape as a cube you can do this:

1. Select the cube
2. Switch to edit mode
3. Switch to Face selection [image]
4. Select the upper face
5. Hit <kbd>G</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd> then enter the half of your cube height, with a minus sign (to move the selected face downwards along Z) and then confirm.

eg: if your cube has a height of 2 (those are blender units), you should enter <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: @Tak, that would make the cube 0.5 BU taller... did you meant -0.5? wrong again. What if the cube is 3 BU tall...? and what if the object is not a cube...?

Comment: @Nick, this answer does not work at all, at least as it is now...

Comment: @m.ardito thanks for your comments. The question was about scaling a cube not another more complex object that's why I suggested the easiest way.

Comment: @Tak so, you guess he knows how to scale every other shape, but is asking for the cube? and also, it does not work at all...

Comment: @m.ardito I'm not sure what you mean by it doesn't work at all? the value `0.5` can be changed by the user, also if the user accepted it then it means it solved his problem I guess.

Comment: I think Nick accepted too soon, maybe he found another way later... GZ0.5 will move that face UP of 0.5 BU, is that correct for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52680/discussion-between-tak-and-m-ardito).

Comment: just corrected Tak's  answer a bit...

Answer (score 2):

Tak's answer will work only with objects as simple as a cube. Any other shape will need to learn a different technique: managing pivot point for transforms. How could you apply that to a UV or ICO sphere, or a Monkey?

Here is how you can do with whatever shape you have: let's take the UV sphere example:

1. you need to put the 3D cursor where you wish your "scaling" will to be calculated from. This point in cube would be the (four) bottom face vertices, but in a UV sphere is the (only) bottom vertex, so, let's select that vertex, and "snap" the cursor to it.

[image]

2. Then, switch the global pivot point to "3D cursor": you see that the 3D cursor is still at the very bottom of the UV sphere.

[image]

3. Now you can scale on Z by 0.5 (this means 50% when scaling, while 0.5 Blender Units while moving), and it works as intended, but is by far more general.

[image]

This works both scaling in edit or object mode,

[image]

just remember that object mode scaling sometimes needs to be "applied" to become as if you did in edit mode (after applying, the mesh is identical, but the object results to have no scaling: this may have implications on later transform and interactions with modifiers, etc.)